# I want to execute an SQL query to upload images in PHP. The query fetches data but doesn't execute

Tags: php, mysql

[`My Database Table`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ULl5.png)

[After execution Query Looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fhzw1.png)

After executing , the inner failed echo appears

```
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label for="in-15" class="control-label">Listing Type</label>
                              <select id="in-15" required name="listing_type" data-placeholder="---" class="form-control">
                                <option label=" "></option>
                                <option value="Sale">Sale</option>
                                <option value="Rent">Rent</option>

                              </select>
                            </div>


                           <div class="form-group">
                              <label for="in-2" class="control-label">Property type</label>
                              <select id="in-2" required name="property_type" data-placeholder="---" class="form-control">
                                <option label=" "></option>
                                <option value="Residential">House</option>
                                <option value="SOHO">Flate</option>

                                <option value="Land">Land</option>
                              </select>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label for="in-11" class="control-label">Price</label>
                              <input id="in-11" name="price" type="number" min="0" placeholder="" required class="form-control">
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label for="in-11" class="control-label">Area(In Marla)</label>
                              <input id="in-11" name="area" type="number" min="0" placeholder="" required class="form-control">
                            </div>



                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label for="in-11" class="control-label">No of Bedrooms</label>
                              <input id="in-11" name="beds" type="number" min="0" placeholder="" required class="form-control">
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label for="in-11" class="control-label">No of Bethrooms</label>
                              <input id="in-11" name="bathroom" type="number" min="0" placeholder="" required class="form-control">
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label for="in-11" class="control-label">No of Girages</label>
                              <input id="in-11" name="girages" type="number" min="0" placeholder="" required class="form-control">
                            </div>



                             <div id='form-block-3' class='form__block js-form-block'>
                                                  <div class='row'>
                                                    <div class='form-group form-group--description'>
                                                      <label for='in-13' class='control-label'>address</label>
                                                      <textarea name='address' id='in-13' required data-parsley-trigger='keyup' data-parsley-minlength='200' data-parsley-validation-threshold='10' data-parsley-minlength-message='You need to enter at least a 200 caracters long comment..' class='form-control form-control--description'>

                                                      </textarea>
                                                    </div>
                                                  </div>
                                                </div>

                             <div id='form-block-3' class='form__block js-form-block'>
                                                  <div class='row'>
                                                    <div class='form-group form-group--description'>
                                                      <label for='in-13' class='control-label'>Description</label>
                                                      <textarea name='desc' id='in-13' required data-parsley-trigger='keyup' data-parsley-minlength='200' data-parsley-validation-threshold='10' data-parsley-minlength-message='You need to enter at least a 200 caracters long comment..' class='form-control form-control--description'>

                                                      </textarea>
                                                    </div>
                                                  </div>
                                                </div>




                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label for="in-11" class="control-label">Image 1</label>
                              <input id="in-11" name="file1" type="file"  placeholder="" required class="form-control">
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label for="in-11" class="control-label">Image 2</label>
                              <input id="in-11" name="file2" type="file"  placeholder="" required class="form-control">
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label for="in-11" class="control-label">Image 3</label>
                              <input id="in-11" name="file3" type="file"  placeholder="" required class="form-control">
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label for="in-11" class="control-label">Image 4</label>
                              <input id="in-11" name="file4" type="file"  placeholder="" required class="form-control">
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label for="in-11" class="control-label">Image 5</label>
                              <input id="in-11" name="file5" type="file"  placeholder="" required class="form-control">
                            </div>                      
                          </div>
                          <div class="row">
                            <button type="submit" name="add_adv" class="form__submit">Submit</button>
                          </div>
                        </form>



<?php

                        if(isset($_POST['add_adv']))

                            {

                              $listing_type = $_POST['listing_type'];
                              $property_type = $_POST['property_type'];
                              $beds = $_POST['beds'];
                              $bathroom = $_POST['bathroom'];
                              $price = $_POST['price'];
                              $girages = $_POST['girages'];
                              $address = $_POST['address'];
                              $area = $_POST['area'];
                              $desc = $_POST['desc'];

                              $file1 = $_FILES['file1']['name'];
                              $tmp_file1 = $_FILES['file1']['tmp_name'];

                              $file2 = $_FILES['file2']['name'];
                              $tmp_file2 = $_FILES['file2']['tmp_name'];

                              $file3 = $_FILES['file3']['name'];
                              $tmp_file3 = $_FILES['file3']['tmp_name'];

                              $file4 = $_FILES['file4']['name'];
                              $tmp_file4 = $_FILES['file4']['tmp_name'];

                              $file5 = $_FILES['file5']['name'];
                              $tmp_file5 = $_FILES['file5']['tmp_name'];

                              $loc1 = '../assets/img/'.$file1;
                              $loc2 = '../assets/img/'.$file2;
                              $loc3 = '../assets/img/'.$file3;
                              $loc4 = '../assets/img/'.$file4;
                              $loc5 = '../assets/img/'.$file5;

                              $move1 = move_uploaded_file( $tmp_file1 , $loc1 );
                              $move2 = move_uploaded_file( $tmp_file2 , $loc2 );
                              $move3 = move_uploaded_file( $tmp_file3 , $loc3 );
                              $move4 = move_uploaded_file( $tmp_file4 , $loc4 );
                              $move5 = move_uploaded_file( $tmp_file5 , $loc5 );


                              if( $move1 && $move2  && $move3  && $move4  && $move5  )


                                {
                                          echo $insert_adver = "

                                             INSERT INTO property
                                             ( propertytype , datetime , price , area , desc ,  address , bedroom , bathroom
                                                ,gerages , listingtype , seller_id , smimage , status , smimage2 , smimage3
                                                , smimage4 , smimage5 )

                                            values ( '$property_type' , NOW() ,  '$price' ,  
                                            '$area' , '$desc' , '$address' ,'$beds' 
                                            ,'$bathroom' , '$girages' ,'$listing_type' , '$_SESSION[id]' 
                                            ,'$file1' ,'0' ,'$file2' ,'$file3' ,'$file4' , '$file5')    



                                              ";

                                              $exec_this_query = mysqli_query( $con , $insert_adver );

                                              if($exec_this_query)
                                              {

                                                echo"<script>alert('successfully uploaded ! Please wait for Approval from Admin')</script>";  
                                              }

                                              else
                                              {

                                                  echo"<script>alert('Inner FAILED !')</script>";


                                              }

                                }

                                else

                                    {


                                        echo"<script>alert('FAILED !')</script>";


                                    }





                            }








                    ?>
```

Comment: Take a look at [ask] and try to write a [mcve].

Comment: Instead of getting a static "Ooops" message, get the actual error MySQL throws you, `echo mysqli_error($con);` - and this is a lot of code to read through, you should probably try to narrow it down to the relevant parts, and format your code better - this is a little messy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Image of my Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bz2Qc.png)

The mistake was that i had used desc attribute in Table which is a reserved word..